# A RenderFlex overflowed by 99761 pixels on the bottom

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my code, I am passing the "Keyname" to the stateless widget, this widget is wrapped with Flexible widget in a different dart file.

I am getting this error:

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

Here is the code:

```
Flexible(
          flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      KeyBoardButtonFirstRow(
                        width: deviceWidth / 6,
                        color: Color(0xfffdc40d),
                        keyName: '2nF',
                      ),
                      KeyBoardButtonFirstRow(
                        width: deviceWidth / 6,
                        color: Color(0xff52e2fe),
                      ),
                      KeyBoardButtonFirstRow(
                        width: deviceWidth / 2,
                        color: Color(0xffabbfc5),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),


class KeyBoardButtonFirstRow extends StatelessWidget {
final String keyName;
final double width;
final Color color;

KeyBoardButtonFirstRow({this.keyName, this.width, this.color});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 30.0,
    width: width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: color,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
      blurRadius: 2.0,
    )],
  ),
  child: Text(keyName),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes you you need to make to your code,

```
class Test0 extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _Test0State createState() => _Test0State();
 }

class _Test0State extends State<Test0> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [

                          KeyBoardButtonFirstRow(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                            color: Color(0xfffdc40d),
                            keyName: '2nF',
                          ),
                        ],
                   )
              ])
          ))
      ],
    ),
  );
 }
 }
 
 class KeyBoardButtonFirstRow extends StatelessWidget {
   final String keyName;
   final double width;
   final Color color;

   KeyBoardButtonFirstRow({this.keyName, this.width, this.color});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  height: 30.0,
  width: width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: color,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        blurRadius: 2.0,
      )
    ],
  ),
  child: Text(keyName),
  );
 }
}
```

Here I have Scaffold, in your case, it could be any **constrained widget**.